# How to get the browser page URL without the domain name in the component's jsp/html aem6.3?

Tags: aem, sightly

Let's say my page url is `www.test.com/myproject/en/test.html`. Now I need to get '`/myproject/en/test.html`' in my component's jsp/html file. We are using sightly.

I am trying to use the below code to achieve it-

```
<script>
    var x = window.location.pathname;
alert(x);
</script>
```

I am getting the value `/myproject/en/test.html` in variable `x`, but not able to use the value in the meta tag as below-

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://mywebsite.com ${x}">
```

How can I pass `x`'s value here in the meta tag? Or, is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Sightly is server side language, you won't be able to access the Client Javascript variable inside sightly markup as that is processed before Javascript runs on the browser. You could look at [Sightly global objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/global-objects.html), you can use `currentPage` object in JS Use API to get path. If you have resolved the path using `resourceResolver`, that would also be available. But if you have handled urls using rewrite rules on web server then this would needs to be handled differently.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly use the request object (Java-backed Objects) provided by Sightly.

For complete URL:

```
${request.requestURL.toString}
```

For current page path:

```
${currentPage.path} // returns only the path without domain name
```

For specific parts of a URL:

```
${request.scheme} // returns https or http
${request.serverName} // returns server name eg: stackoverflow.com
${request.serverPort} // returns server port eg: 4502 for AEM
${request.requestURI} // returns URI eg: /content/test.html
```

Concatenate the specific parts to create your desired url in Sighlty:

```
<sly data-sly-test.scheme="${request.scheme}"/>
<sly data-sly-test.servername="${request.serverName}"/>
<sly data-sly-test.serverport="${request.serverPort}"/>
<sly data-sly-test.uri="${request.requestURI}"/>

<link rel="icon" href="${scheme}://${servername}:${serverport}${uri}">
```

Methods available under request object: https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/SlingHttpServletRequest.html

Other helpful HTL Global Objects:
https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/global-objects.html

Answer (score 2):

The `<script>` javascript is a clientside code executed at browser.
Sightly/jsp is server side code which would have already compiled and rendered at serverside. Your favicon code would be server side rendering. Here is example:

**Sightly**:

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://mywebsite.com/${currentPage.path}">
```

**Drawback**: 
Your domain is hardcoded as mywebsite.com. All environments;qa, uat, staging will show incorrect domain.

**Better implementation**: Use externalizer.

```
<sly data-sly-use.page="com.mywebsite.core.PageHelper"/>
<link rel="icon" href="${page.currentPageUrl}">
```

and create a sling model helper

```
@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class)
public class PageHelper {

@OSGiService
private Externalizer externalizer;
@ScriptVariable
private Page currentPage;
@ScriptVariable
private ResourceResolver resolver;
String currentPageUrl;

@PostConstruct
protected void initModel() {
   currentPageUrl = externalizer.publishLink(resolver, currentPage.getPath()) + ".html";
}

public String getCurrentPageUrl() {
   return currentPageUrl;
}
```

Bonus: [wcm core](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/bundles/core/src/main/java/com/adobe/cq/wcm/core/components/models/Page.java) has inbuilt getFavIcons implementation. It can be leveraged.